# data is being overwritten in my firebase database.how to fix it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am adding data from multiple edit texts to my firebase database. it adds fine but when I try to add it again it doesnt create new object. it overwrites the previous one.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button logout;
    EditText etfinalyear,etcnic,etname,etpaygroup,etregion,etcurrentposition,etcurrentaddress,etphonenumber,etmobilenumber;
    FirebaseAuth mfirebaseauth;
    Button btnsave;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mauthstatelistener;
    DatabaseReference reff;
    users user;
    ImageView ntc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        ntc = findViewById(R.id.ntc);
        etfinalyear = findViewById(R.id.edittextfinyear);
        etcnic = findViewById(R.id.edittextcnic);
        etname = findViewById(R.id.edittextname);
        etpaygroup = findViewById(R.id.edittextpaygroup);
        etregion = findViewById(R.id.edittextregion);
        etcurrentposition = findViewById(R.id.edittextcurrentposition);
        etcurrentaddress = findViewById(R.id.edittextcurrentaddress);
        etphonenumber = findViewById(R.id.edittextphonenumber);
        etmobilenumber = findViewById(R.id.edittextmobilenumber);
        btnsave = findViewById(R.id.save);
        logout = findViewById(R.id.signout);
        reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent logout = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(logout);


            }
        });
        user = new users();
        btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Long phn = Long.parseLong(etphonenumber.getText().toString());
                Long mob = Long.parseLong(etmobilenumber.getText().toString());
                user.setCnic(etcnic.getText().toString());
                user.setFinyear(etfinalyear.getText().toString());
                user.setName(etname.getText().toString());
                user.setPaygroup(etpaygroup.getText().toString());
                user.setDirectorate(etregion.getText().toString());
                user.setCurrentposition(etcurrentposition.getText().toString());
                user.setResidentialaddress(etcurrentaddress.getText().toString());
                user.setPhonenumber(phn);
                user.setMobilenumber(mob);
                reff.child("user1").setValue(user);
                //reff.push().setValue(user);
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Data Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you were pushing at the same reference that is why it was replacing and
Please make sure the `String` you are passing in child method `.child("user1")`    should be exact like in firebase.
,
try this-

```
 user = new users();
btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Long phn = Long.parseLong(etphonenumber.getText().toString());
        Long mob = Long.parseLong(etmobilenumber.getText().toString());
        user.setCnic(etcnic.getText().toString());
        user.setFinyear(etfinalyear.getText().toString());
        user.setName(etname.getText().toString());
        user.setPaygroup(etpaygroup.getText().toString());
        user.setDirectorate(etregion.getText().toString());
        user.setCurrentposition(etcurrentposition.getText().toString());
        user.setResidentialaddress(etcurrentaddress.getText().toString());
        user.setPhonenumber(phn);
        user.setMobilenumber(mob);
        DatabaseReference newRef = reff.child("user1").push();
        newRef.setValue(user);
        //reff.push().setValue(user);
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Data Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pushing to the same reference with `.setValue()` will override all the data inside that child, to update it instead of replacing it, you will need to use a `Map<K,V>` with `updateChildren` in order to just update the fields

```
HashMap<String,Object> mapData = new HashMap<>();

    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Long phn = Long.parseLong(etphonenumber.getText().toString());
                Long mob = Long.parseLong(etmobilenumber.getText().toString());
                user.setCnic(etcnic.getText().toString());
                user.setFinyear(etfinalyear.getText().toString());
                user.setName(etname.getText().toString());
                user.setPaygroup(etpaygroup.getText().toString());
                user.setDirectorate(etregion.getText().toString());
                user.setCurrentposition(etcurrentposition.getText().toString());
                user.setResidentialaddress(etcurrentaddress.getText().toString());
                user.setPhonenumber(phn);
                user.setMobilenumber(mob);
                //Update the map data
                mapData.put("Cnic",user.getCnic());
                mapData.put("Name",user.getName());
                mapData.put("Paygroup",user.getPaygroup());
                mapData.put("Directorate",user.getDirectorate());
                mapData.put("CurrentPos",user.getCurrentposition());
                mapData.put("ResidentialAddress",user.getResidentialAddress());
                mapData.put("Phone",user.getPhoneNumber());
                mapData.put("Mobile",user.getMobileNumber());
                reff.child("user1").updateChildren(mapData);

                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Data Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

If you need to create a random push ID for each object, do this

```
 reff.child("user1").push().updateChildren(mapData);
```